# ¿Como se realizan las condicionales if en jQuery - javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Veran, tengo un pedazo de codigo que solo sirve para verificar *si un numero es mayor a otro*, todo esto con `html-jQuery`, les dejo el codigo:

```js
$("#ver1").click(function(){
  if($("#a1").val() > $("#a2").val()){           
      alert("El rango de tiempo es incorrecto");
  }else{
      alert("ok");
  }
});

$("#ver2").click(function(){
  if(Number($("#a1").val()) > Number($("#a2").val())){           
      alert("El rango de tiempo es incorrecto");
  }else{
      alert("ok");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="a1" value="3">
<input type="text" id="a2" value="12">

<button id="ver1">ver1</button>
<button id="ver2">ver2</button>
```

En el botón **ver1** la condicional "no sirve" por así decirlo, la razón es que no sé la comparación que realiza.

En el botón **ver2** la condicional si cumple su función, por lo menos como yo lo deseo.

> Cual es la comparación que se realiza en el boton **ver1**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Las condiciones no son el problema, el problema es el tipo de datos que estás comparando, el `input` devuelve como valor un `string` y no puedes comparar que un `string` sea mayor a otro (no en su valor, si podrías hacerlo en su longitud pero ese no es el caso), por eso al convertir tus datos a número usando el método `Number()` te funciona correctamente la comparación.

De hecho al comparar dos `string` por su longitud estarías comparando también dos elementos numéricos ya que `.length` devuelve un valor de tipo número.

```js
$("#ver1").click(function(){
  console.log(typeof $("#a1").val());
  console.log(typeof $("#a2").val());
  
  if($("#a1").val() > $("#a2").val()){           
      console.log("El rango de tiempo es incorrecto");
  }else{
      console.log("ok");
  }
});

$("#ver2").click(function(){
  console.log(typeof Number($("#a1").val()));
  console.log(typeof Number($("#a2").val()));

  if(Number($("#a1").val()) > Number($("#a2").val())){           
      console.log("El rango de tiempo es incorrecto");
  }else{
      console.log("ok");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="a1" value="3">
<input type="text" id="a2" value="12">

<button id="ver1">ver1</button>
<button id="ver2">ver2</button>
```

Comment: entonces en la primera opción estaría comparando tamaños? o simplemente esta mal condicionada?

Comment: No, para comparar tamaños tendrías que usar .length, simplemente en la primera opción estás diciendo que un string sea mayor a otro, sin importar que el valor del string sea un numero conocido por nosotros no deja de ser string, seria como comparar que el string "casa" sea mayor al string "perro"